# EF Many To Many Join - Lazy Loading Disabled

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5, code-first, entity-relationship

Here is my scenario:

```
public class Contact 
{
    public Guid ContactId { get; set; }
    ........
    public Guid WorkspaceId { get; set; }
    public Workspace Workspace { get; set; }
}

public class Workspace
{
    public Guid WorkspaceId { get; set; }
    ........
    public ICollection<Contact> ReferencedContacts { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Contact> OwnedContacts { get; set; }
}
```

The logic is the following one: A contact can't exists outside a workspace (means that the workspace owns the contact).
A user has a workspace, and it places the 'owned contacts' in it (owned contact = the contact information describes the users such as profession, name, address, etc).
Also a user workspace can hold a reference to contacts owned by other users (here comes the join table which stores the relation between a workspace and the referenced contacts).

```
public WorkspaceMap()
{
    ....
    HasMany(w => w.ReferencedContacts).WithMany().Map(mp =>
    {
        mp.ToTable("WorkspaceReferencedContacts");
        mp.MapLeftKey("WorkspaceId");
        mp.MapRightKey("ContactId");
        });
}

public ContactMap()
{
    ......
    HasRequired(c => c.Workspace).WithMany(w => w.OwnedContacts).HasForeignKey(c =>   c.WorkspaceId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    Property(c => c.WorkspaceId).HasColumnName("WorkpaceId");
}
```

What I am trying to do is to get all referenced contacts for a specific workspace using query methods. The SQL version of the query would be the following one:

SELECT * FROM dbo.Contacts c
INNER JOIN dbo.WorkspaceReferencedContacts wc ON wc.ContactId = c.ContactId
WHERE wc.WorkspaceId = '57F685C0-428C-44C3-8708-F30B5AF34CAE';

I have approached many ways without any success. **Please note that lazy loading is disabled (there is no point to discuss why...)**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ...get all referenced contacts for a specific workspace...

I think:

```
var contacts = context.Workspaces
    .Where(w => w.WorkspaceId == "57F685C0-428C-44C3-8708-F30B5AF34CAE")
    .Select(w => w.ReferencedContacts)
    .SingleOrDefault();
```